# Pass dynamic param to @MapKey("${dynamicParam}") (My-Batis)

Tags: java, mybatis

Is it possible to pass dynamic param to @MapKey annotation ?? I have to dynamically choose the key of the table for constructing Table result in a Map.

I have tries passing the dynamic param same as we do for any sql query using ${} syntax.

Does not Work

```
@MapKey("${tablePk}")
 @Select("${sql}")
 Map doGenericOperation(@Param("sql") String sql, @Param("tablePk") String tablePk);
```

Works

```
@MapKey("id")
 @Select("${sql}")
 Map doGenericOperation(@Param("sql") String sql, @Param("tablePk") String tablePk);
```

Map Key does not get apply in this case. However if I pass it if like 
@Map("id") works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

As you pass the entire sql as a string, it should be possible to assign fixed alias to the primary key beforehand.

Also, it is fairly easy to achieve what you want without using `@MapKey`.

```java
@Select("${sql}")
List<Map<String, ?>> doGenericOperation_Internal(@Param("sql") String sql);

default Map<?, Map<String, ?>> doGenericOperation(String sql, String tablePk) {
  return doGenericOperation_Internal(sql).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.get(tablePk), e -> e));
}
```

Just be sure NOT to pass any user provided string as part of `sql` to avoid SQL injection!

Comment: That is taken care of.